# How to make a certain pattern move

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

I need to do so that the view can only move around in a circle with a certain radius. 
How can I implement this?

[The circle must move around the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnFs8.png)
How to make the circle move around in circles. I have already implemented the function of moving a circle, only this remains...

Answer (score 0):

Though i think you should give more context, to have a 2D object move in a circle in a 2D space, you have multiple options:

1. Calculate the distance between the object to the center of the circle and move it away if to close of closer if too far away. You'd have to do that every frame and it would be jumpy.
2. Calculate a 90 degree angle to the line from the object to the center and only allow movement in these directions. Could be combined with option 1 for more stability, but becomes resource costly.

Thats all i can think of for this vague question. If a mathematical description was what you wanted.

Comment: If the movement is not user controlled you could just hardcode the relative positions over time.